display array to google bar chart correctly
I get an array dataset from a query like this,
0=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 15
     "sede" : "Chillan"
     "curso" : "energia y sostenibilidad amb"
}
 1=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 56
     "sede" : "Concpecion"
     "curso" : "energia y sostenibilidad amb"
}
 2=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 19
     "sede" : "Los Angeles"
     "curso" : "energia y sostenibilidad amb"
}
 3=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 15
     "sede" : "Chillan"
     "curso" : "Introduccion al BIM"
}
 4=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 38
     "sede" : "Concpecion"
     "curso" : "Introduccion al BIM"
}
 5=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 59
     "sede" : "Los Angeles"
     "curso" : "Introduccion al BIM"
}
 6=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 28
     "sede" : "Chillan"
     "curso" : "Sustentabilidad Ambiental"
} 
 7=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 12
     "sede" : "Concpecion"
     "curso" : "Sustentabilidad Ambiental"
}
 8=>{
    "num_inscritos_curso": 36
     "sede" : "Los Angeles"
     "curso" : "Sustentabilidad Ambiental"
}

I need to loop on it so I can display an horizontal bar chart with the names of the course(curso) showing 1 time for every course, instead when I loop I get 9 bars instead of 3
how can I organize the array to display like that .I hardcoded the 2 last columns within the loop, I need to replace it for the following num_inscritos_curso
    function drawEscuelaCursoChart() {

     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Cursos', 'Chillan', 'Concepcion', 'Los Angeles'],
     @foreach($escuela_construccion as $key=>$value)
         ["{{ @$value->curso}}", {{ @$value->num_inscritos_curso }}, 44, 25 ],
     @endforeach
     ]);

     var options = {
       chart: {
         title: 'Escuela Construcción, Prevencion de Riesgos y Medioambiente',
         subtitle: 'Inscripciones por Sede',
       },
       bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
     };

     var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('stackbar_escuela_curso'));

     chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
     } 
 

Course names are repeated because I have problems displaying  the array inside the loop. I need to show the graphic like this example:
energia y sostenibilidad amb -> 3 graphic bars
Introduccion al BIM  -> 3 graphic bars
Sustentabilidad Ambiental -> 3 graphic bars

I get instead:

